# Find count of multiline in an Excel cell starting with delimiter -

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking to find formula which gives me count of -> how many line in multiline of the cell are begining with - (hyphen)

for e.g. if cell contains

```
how are you keeping up
-I am well and need toy
-"You" are asking wrong question
 <you are wrong>
-why should i reply you
```

sum count of qualified multiline is = 3

can anyone help me out here please

Comment: With VBA this would be easy enough, but without VBA it might be fairly hard. Does a VBA solution work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you first lines *never* start with an hyphen, or at least do not count towards the total, then try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10)&"-","")))/2
```

If your first line can also start with an hyphen and therefor count towards the total, try:

```
=(LEN(CHAR(10)&A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(CHAR(10)&A1,CHAR(10)&"-","")))/2
```

Comment: This will give a false result of the text will contain a `-` somewhere else then at the start of (multi-)line. The vba solution is exactly what you asked.

Comment: @user14618570, that's a false statement. Have you tried it?

Comment: I haven't just read through it and sounded logically. How does it work recognizing the first character? Is char(10) equal to break of lines?

Comment: That's correct @user14618570. It's only replacing the occurrences of a linebreak and hyphen together.

Comment: Wow, never new that's possible!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a VBA solution:

```
Function CountLines(text As String, Optional flag As String = "") As Long
    'counts all lines in text which starts with flag
    Dim i As Long, count As Long
    Dim lines As Variant
    
    lines = Split(text, vbLf)
    For i = LBound(lines) To UBound(lines)
        If Mid(lines(i), 1, Len(flag)) = flag Then
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next i
    CountLines = count
End Function
```

If this is in a standard code module, the example text in `A1` and in `B1` you enter the formula `=CountLines(A1,"-")`, it will evaluate to 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the first line in the potential count, then, in Windows Excel 2013+, you can try:

```
=COUNTA(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,">","&gt;"),"<","&lt;"),"""","&quot;"),CHAR(10),"</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[starts-with(text(),'-')]"))
```

- Replace illegal xml characters `"`,`<`, and `>`
- Create an XML by splitting into nodes based on the `LF` character
- Use xpath `//s[starts-with(text(),'-')]` to return only those nodes that start with a hyphen.
- `COUNTA` to return the count of those nodes